# How to find number of member in group?

Tags: mysql, left-join

How to find count member in group where group_title = notitle
. my db is mysql.

```
groups table  -> id | group_number | notification_id | group_title | salavat_count | status
                 32         1kk           NULL          notitle           0          idle
                 33         2k            NULL          notitle           0          idle

groups_members table -> id | groups_id | members_id
                        1       32          222
```

I want show mew:

```
groups.id | memberCount
    32           1
    33           0
```

Comment: show us the expected  result

Comment: And what you have try...

Comment: my query is: 
SELECT COUNT(*),groups.*
FROM groups_members 
JOIN groups 
on groups.id = groups_members.`groups_id` 
where groups.group_title = 'notitle'
group by groups.id;

result:

Comment: i want:
count(*) | groups.id

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Use enough words & sentences to say what you mean. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM groups_member JOIN groups on groups.group_number = groups_member.id where groups.group_title = 'notitle'

Comment: tanx. this solution working but in addition i want show me group is zero member.

Answer (score 0):

I find it.

```
SELECT COUNT(groups_members.id),groups.*
FROM groups_members 
right JOIN groups 
on groups.id = groups_members.`groups_id` 
where groups.group_title = 'notitle'
group by groups.id;
```